Authentication works in Laravel 11, but it returns null . Why?
In Laravel, I can sign up and log in without any issues using Breeze.
In my table, I have:
$table->enum('role', ['admin', 'user']);
Here’s how your bootstrap/app.php file looks:
<?php

use App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
        then: function () {
            Route::prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
        },
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->alias([
            'admin' => AdminMiddleware::class
        ]);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

Middleware file looks:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
       
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role === 'admin') {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect()->back(); // veya başka bir yönlendirme
        }
    }
}

"I am logging in, but Tinker returns this:"
> $user = Auth::user()->id;

   WARNING  Attempt to read property "id" on null.

= null

> $user = Auth::user();

neden olur ?
"I am able to authenticate and am redirected to my dashboard page. However, the route where I use middleware directly calls back(), and my user is coming in as null."

Tinker uses a separate interactive instance and doesn't share the session with the browser so the test with Tinker has not relevance.

In my effort to continue the page
Attempt to read property "role" on nul
